# Correct way to update values for animations

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to generate some animations with d3.js. I don't really have a lot of problems with the animation itself (I'm working with tween function, and it seems that I've understood the basics), but with the updating of the values, that should come from a json file that I read periodically.

Basically:

```
 d3.json(filename, function(error, json) {
     if (error) {
         console.log(error);
         return;
     }

     callback(json);
  });
```

In the callback function I try to get the differences between the old and the new data, and prepare the corresponding interpolation functions that will be needed in the tweens (if some value has changed from 0 to 10, I prepare a function in this range).

Most of my interpolation functions are similar to (as you can see, you need to specify the old and the new data):

```
d3.interpolate(old, new),            
d3.interpolateRgb(oldColor, newColor),
```

After that, I select some elements (what I need to animate), lookup in the differences collection and, if the interpolation function is defined, perform the animation.

```
someElements
      .transition()
      .duration(Dashboard.settings.timers.animationTime)
      .tween("d", function() {
         return function(t) {
           var data = lookupOnCollectionById(this.__data__.id, changes);

          if (data.interpolationFunctions !== undefined) {
            //Perform animation
          }
       };
```

This works, and works fine. The thing is, I understand that the concept (or one of them) behind d3.js is let the animations being driven by the data. What I'm doing is basically do the process myself and just use the framework to "render".

As far as I know, on every selection I have the data element ready to be used with the binded data, but obviously I don't have the "previous" data. I'm not really sure if this has to be accomplished as I'm doing or maybe I'm reinventing the wheel. Has d3.js some already existing mechanism to work with data changes?.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you set a new attribute value with a transition, the animation will automatically start at the previous value. It is only in cases when the default tween doesn't work (properly) that you need to specify a custom tween and may need to store the old data explicitly. You haven't described what your transitions are -- maybe you can simply use the standard tweens?

Comment: Thanks Lars, very interesting indeed. I've used the tween function because I wanted to modify the current degree of an arc like here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750941. I don't know if that can be done in a different way :)

Comment: It sounds like in this case you would need to store the previous value.

Comment: Hi Lars, If you are pretty confident about the need of store the previous data, I'd like to vote it as an answer, if that's OK for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as an answer with some more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a new attribute value with a transition, the animation will automatically start at the previous value. In this case, there is no need to store the data explicitly, as D3 will take care of everything.

It is only in cases when the default tween doesn't work (properly) that you need to specify a custom tween and may need to store the old data explicitly. A prime example of this are pie charts (see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410)). When updating pie charts, you can't let D3 use the default tween to interpolate the areas covered by the pie segments -- you need a custom tween that uses an arc generator to compute the intermediate paths. For this, you need to create the interpolation between old and new angles explicitly -- for that, you need to store the old data.

In the example I've linked to, the old data (which in this case is just the angle) is stored as part of the DOM. You could of course store it in a separate object and then index into that as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an update function that runs when the new data is loaded, and that function computes a data join, you don't have to keep track of what the old data was. d3 will handle that for you. For instance, if your `callback()` function joins data to a selection like this...

```
function callback(json) {

  d3.selectAll('.someClass')
    // this is the data join
    .data(json);

  // do other things with the selection
}
```

... then you can choose whether to apply your transition to elements that already had data bound to them and now have new data (known as the 'update' selection), or to the `.enter()` or `.exit()` selection.

```
function callback(json) {

  // joins the json data to all elements with class someClass
  // and stores the selection in a variable sel
  var sel = d3.selectAll('.someClass');
    .data(json);

  // this is the 'update' section where existing elements 
  //  are updated with new data, transitions applied here
  //  transition from the old values to the new values
  sel.transition().duration(1000)
    // update transition attributes go here

  // this is the 'enter' section where additional datapoints
  //  in the updated data are used to create new elements
  sel.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'someClass')
    .transition().duration(1000)
    // enter transition attributes go here

  // this is the 'exit' section where you remove elements that
  //  no longer have applicable data in the new dataset
  sel.exit().transition().duration(1000)
     // example of exit transition
    .attr('opacity', 0)
    .remove();

}
```

I hope that was fairly clear. If not, or you just want to read further about data joins, Mike Bostock (the author of d3) wrote an excellent post about the subject called [**>> Thinking with Joins**](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)

Comment: Hi jshanley and thanks! In fact, I don't know if I'm getting the full picture yet, but I've used the data joins for other parts of the 'rendering'. But I don't know how to apply them with the interpolation functions. I've edited my post and added two of them, just to clarify what of them I'm using.

Comment: Thanks again jshanley, I think that my question wasn't very well explained at first. Thanks for your efforts anyway.